# (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openDatabase on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)) flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

(MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openDatabase on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)) flutter

in internet thay say to force flutter clean + flutter pub get, but it didnt worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in my case.
I was using construction:

```
return await openDatabase(
  path,
  version: 1,
  onCreate: _onCreate,
  onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) => onUpdateTable(db),
);
```

Which was wrong,
instead try

```
sqfliteFfiInit();
return await databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase(
  path,
  options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
    version: 1,
    onCreate: _onCreate,
    onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) => onUpdateTable(db),
  ),
);
```